# Can every singular matrix be transformed into a diag matrix with only 0s and 1s along the diagonal by multiplication with an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

From linear algebra it is know that by choosing a "good" basis, that is multiplying a matrix with an invertible matrix $P$ from one side and with another invertible matrix $S^{-1}$ from the other side, a matrix $A$ can be brought into the form
$$
P A S^{-1}
= \begin{pmatrix}
E_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $E_r$ is the $r \times r$ identity matrix and $r = \text{rank}(A)$.

This motivated the following

> **Question:** For every singular matrix $S$ does there exists an *invertible* matrix $M$ such that $MS$ (or $SM$) is a diagonal matrix containing only ones and zeros on the diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1& 1}$. It cannot be brought into diagonal form by multiplication with a single invertible matrix. If $M$ is invertible, then the rows of $MS$ and the columns of $SM$ are multiples of $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ or $\pmatrix{0&0}$. Hence, these matrices will can only be diagonal if they would be zero, but this implies $S=0$ by  invertibility of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

If such a M exists then we will have $S = M^{-1} D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with at least one zero on the diagonal, and hence at least one zero column . This would imply that $S$ must have at least one zero column.

So any singular matrix without any zero column will be a counterexample.